# Multi channel search YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is it possible to search multiple channels, with the YouTube API v3 ?

I can search a single channel successfully. Also is there a cost to search each channel and merging the data or is it better to search YouTube and filter by channel at an application level ?